# toHaveBeenCalled fails even if function is called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive which is :

```
angular.module( 'app' )
    .directive( 'infiniteScroll', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                canLoad: '=',
                fetchData: '&',
                viewportSelector: '@'
            },
            link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
                var offset = parseInt( attrs.threshold ) || 0;
                var e = document.querySelector( attrs.viewportSelector );
                e.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
                    if ( scope.canLoad) {
                        scope.$apply( function() {
                            scope.fetchData();
                        } );
                    }
                } );
            }
        };
    } );
```

Here is my test for that:

```
describe( 'infiniteScroll directive : check ', function() {
    beforeEach( inject( function( $compile ) {
        scope.canLoad = true;
        element = angular.element( ' <div infinite-scroll fetch-data="addItems()" can-load="canLoad" viewport-selector=".selector">' );
        viewport = angular.element( ' <div class="selector" style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow-y:auto;"></div>' );
        var content = angular.element( ' <div style="height:800px;width:100px;"></div>' );
        viewport.append( content );
        angular.element( document.body ).append( viewport );
        angular.element( document.body ).append( element );
        element = $compile( element )( scope );
        scope.$apply();
        isolated = element.isolateScope();
    } ) );

    it( 'should check for scroll function', inject( function() {
        spyOn( isolated, 'fetchData' );
        viewport[ 0 ].scrollTop = 800;
        expect( isolated.fetchData ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    } ) );
} );
```

When I run the test case I can see (in istanbul coverage reporter) that the scope.fetchData() is called but my expectation 'expect( isolated.fetchData ).toHaveBeenCalled()' fails.
What am I doing wrong here?

Tried waiting for sometime by:

```
    it( 'should check for scroll function', inject( function() {
        jasmine.clock().install();
        viewport[ 0 ].scrollTop = 800;
        jasmine.clock().tick( 2000 );
        expect( isolated.fetchData ).toHaveBeenCalled();
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    } ) );
```

But this also did not work.

Comment: I'd assume you might run into a concurrency issue here. Try waiting for a few milliseconds before checking maybe?

Comment: @kasoban Thnaks. I tried that and edited the questions accordingly. But it still has the same issue.

Comment: The fact that your coverage shows that the scope.fetchData() has been called tells you that it called the actual function and not your spy.  That function is being called before your spy is created.